# interact.js won't work on phone(cordova app) gives an error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: jquery, cordova, interact.js, html5-draggable

I'm trying to implement an interactive menu using draggable divs(touch and drag) for my mobile application using interact.js. The Snapping sample from their site doesn't seem to work. It gives the error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null.

Here is my Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
<script src="components/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/interact.js/1.2.8/interact.min.js"></script>

 <style>
  #grid-snap {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #29e;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 5%;
 }  
</style>

<script>
var element = document.getElementById('grid-snap'),
x = 0, y = 0;

interact(element)
  .draggable({
    snap: {
      targets: [
        interact.createSnapGrid({ x: 30, y: 30 })
      ],
      range: Infinity,
      relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
    },
    inertia: true,
    restrict: {
      restriction: element.parentNode,
      elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 },
      endOnly: true
    }
  })
  .on('dragmove', function (event) {
    x += event.dx;
    y += event.dy;

    event.target.style.webkitTransform =
    event.target.style.transform =
        'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%">
    <div id="grid-snap">
    Dragging is constrained to the corners of a grid
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle or a full working example? Do you have the line number and/or line of the error?

Comment: The above code works all fine in the browser, but not on the phone(as a cordova app). The error line shown by the debugger is **cdn.jsdelivr.net/interact.js/1.2.8/interact.min.js:2**

Comment: use the non minified version of react and re run it, error lines from minified js are pretty much worthless